# В Sublime перестало работать ctrl + shift +g

Tags: sublime-text-3

Неожиданно перестала работать данная комбинация клавиш.
До этого всё отлично работало, никаких изменений не вносил.
Нашёл похожую проблему - https://github.com/sergeche/emmet-sublime/issues/569
Кто-то встречался с таким, как можно решить?

Comment: Может кто-то поможет, как прописать данный бинд?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В настройках Sublime (Preferences -> Key Bindings) нужно указать:

`{ "keys": ["ctrl+shift+g"], "command": "emmet_wrap_with_abbreviation" },`